# How to search for a string in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, substring

I need to search whether a mail id is available in the group of IDs seperated by comma.

I am trying with the following code.

It shows 'available' for unavailable IDs also.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample 
AS
  email_id VARCHAR2(1000);
  mail     VARCHAR2(100);    
  BEGIN
    email_id := 'robin@gmail.com, gilbert@rediff.com, osborn@yahoo.com, allwyn@gmail.com, chris@yahoo.com';
    mail := 'chris@gmail.com';

    IF (INSTR(email_id, mail) IS NOT NULL) THEN
      dbms_output.PUT_LINE('available');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.PUT_LINE('sorry');
    END IF;

  END sample;
```

It is not working properly. Please help me.

Comment: User `like` operator.

Comment: You may wish to [Consult The Delightful Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions073.htm#SQLRF00651).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSTR()` would return `0`, if it didn't find a matching substring in the source(Unless the input itself is NULL). So when you check for `NOT NULL`, it always returns `TRUE`.

If it finds a matching substring, it would return the position of the substring in the source.(NUMBER)

So for your case, `LIKE` or `REGEXP_LIKE` should help. 
Still you can go for the below.

```
if(INSTR (EMAIL_ID, MAIL) > 0)
then
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('available');
else 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sorry');
end if;
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) From Oracle.

Comment: @CDurai this answer is always better than newly accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
Hi i guess instead of declaring a full new variable and then using just use LIKE 
operator. I think it should resolve your query.
DECLARE
  lv_var VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  lv_var:='avra14march@gmail.com,shubhojitr@yahoo.co.in';
  IF lv_var LIKE '%avra%' THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Available');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Sorry');
  END IF;
END;

OUTPUT 
------------------------------------------------
anonymous block completed
Available
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi. I am glad it helped you. Can you please the answer :)